# kestrel-dotnetapp.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/dotnet: Permission denied

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, centos, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to install .NET Core(3.1) app in Centos8 using steps given in MS [enter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1) .

Service File as per Microsoft document `/etc/systemd/system/kestrel-dotnetapp.service`

```
[Unit]  
Description= .NET Web API App for centos

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/Application/netcoreapp31
ExecStart=/usr/local/dotnet /var/Application/netcoreapp31/helloapp.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:  
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnetapp
User=user
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When i do > `sudo systemctl start kestrel-dotnetapp.service` am getting error.

> Jun 04 22:51:28 hostname systemd[1827]: kestrel-dotnetapp.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
>   Jun 04 22:51:28 hostname systemd[1827]: kestrel-dotnetapp.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/dotnet: Permission denied
>   -- Subject: Process /usr/local/dotnet could not be executed
>   -- Defined-By: systemd

Find below **ls -la** :

```
[user@hostname dotnet]$ ls -la
total 108
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root    94 Apr 22 09:34 .
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root   154 Jun  4 21:11 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 73048 Apr 22 09:32 dotnet
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root    17 Apr 22 09:34 host
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  1116 Apr 22 09:29 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root    67 Apr 22 09:34 shared
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 31330 Apr 22 09:29 ThirdPartyNotices.txt
```

My application deliverables folder

```
[user@hostname Application]$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root     26 Jun  4 20:53 .
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root root   4096 Jun  4 20:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  2  777 user 4096 Jun  4 20:45 netcoreapp31
```

Answer (score 6):

Found that service is starting when we change path of **ExecStart** to `ExecStart=/usr/local/dotnet/dotnet` . No idea why microsoft blog said till `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet` is enough !

PS: Also if the Linux is SE service files shouldn't be in /home directory

Comment: If you need to check the location of dotnet, use `whereis dotnet`

Answer (score 2):

After reading tons of info, the solution was this:

Put the application into the `/var/www/` instead of the other folder such as /home, root, etc

Simply git clone into there, If the repo is private create git pat/for the organization create another account for more security add a member, and make the pat

git clone example:
`git clone https://YOUR_GITHUB_PAT@github.com/org_or_user/repo`

Service result:

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on Linux

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/UnturnedGuard-api/src/UnturnedGuardAPI.App
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/UnturnedGuard-api/src/UnturnedGuardAPI.App/bin/Debug/net7.0/UnturnedGuardAPI.App.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=www-data
#envs
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then execute command: `systemctl daemon-reload`

Check the status: `sudo systemctl status kestrel-deploy-guide.service`

(if it doesn't start then use `sudo systemctl start kestrel-deploy-guide.service`)

Done!

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours of searching... the answer above is valid
even for Dotnet 5.0 application with default installation and default user pi with custom publish folder:

```
[Service]
 
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/myPublishDirectory

ExecStart=/home/pi/.dotnet/**dotnet** /home/pi/myPublishDirectory/MyApplication.dll

User=pi
...
```

Comment: This should be a comment. This is the same answer than A.K, you only change your username by "pi". By the way, keeping the user "pi" is not very secure.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `**dotnet**`?